# How to put a link into a Django error message

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I want to insert a link to a page inside of my project using the Django error messages something like this

```
 messages.error(request, 'Please click <a href="{% url 'myproject:settings' %} >here </a>')
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try using [`format_html`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/utils/#django.utils.html.format_html):

```
from django.utils.html import format_html
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse


message = format_html('Please click <a href="{}">here</a>', reverse('myproject:settings'))
messages.error(request, message)
```

Using `format_html` means that the string will be marked as safe, so the `<a>` tag should work. Note that I've used `reverse` rather than `{% url %}`, because treating the string as Django template language would be trickier.